# Can't Get Data for Simple Login with HTML to PHP Web Service

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I try to access login service from some web service for user validation directly to html page using jquery, but it seems not working, even when I access the web service with browser the web service work perfectly. Here is the html code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.2.4/css/ionic.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.2.4/css/ionic.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#login").click(function(){
            var username=$("#username").val();
            var password=$("#password").val();
            var dataString="username="+username+"&password="+password+"&login=";
            if($.trim(email).length>0 & $.trim(password).length>0)
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "some url here",
                        data: dataString,
                        crossDomain: true,
                        cache: false,
                        beforeSend: function(){ $("#login").html('Connecting...');},
                        success: function(data){
                            if(data.success=="true")
                                {
                                    localStorage.login="true";
                                    localStorage.username=username;
                                    window.location.href = "index.html";
                                }
                            else if(data.success="false")
                                {
                                    alert("Login error");
                                    $("#login").html('Login');
                                }
                        }
                    });
                }   return false;
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="bar bar-header bar-positive" style="margin-bottom:80px;">
        <a href="index.html" class="button button-clear">Home</a>
        <h1 class="title">Login</h1>
    </div>
    <br/><br/>
    <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="username" />
    <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="password" />
    <button id="login">Login</button>
</body>
```

Even the "beforeSend" code is not working, I mean when I click on Login button the text on it doesn't change to Connecting. How can I make it work?

Comment: check your browser console..does it show any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
$.trim(email).length
```

To

```
$.trim(username).length
```

One more problem in code in `success function`;

```
/* Now */
}else if(data.success="false"){

/* should be == because here we are comparing not assigning */
}else if(data.success=="false"){

/* OR we can remove if part completely because we don't need any comparison if not success  */
}else{
```

One more thing if we are getting the response as `true` or `false` i don't thing it would be string value, it would be Boolean so update code for `success function` like following:

```
success: function(data){
  if(data.success){
    localStorage.login = "true";
    localStorage.username = username;
    window.location.href = "index.html";
  }else{
    alert("Login error");
    $("#login").html('Login');
  }
}
```

And one more problem your code won't execute because here you are trying to reference element that not loaded that is `login button`;

**Use following code with all fixes;**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.2.4/css/ionic.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.2.4/css/ionic.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      /* code wrapped in $(function(){ to make sure the all elemtents loaded before we make use them  */
      $(function(){
        $("#login").click(function(){
          var username = $("#username").val();
          var password = $("#password").val();
          var dataString = "username=" + username + "&password=" + password + "&login=";
          if($.trim(password).length > 0 & $.trim(password).length > 0){
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "some url here",
              data: dataString,
              crossDomain: true,
              cache: false,
              beforeSend: function(){
                $("#login").html('Connecting...');
              },
              success: function(data){
                if(data.success){
                  localStorage.login = "true";
                  localStorage.username = username;
                  window.location.href = "index.html";
                }else{
                  alert("Login error");
                  $("#login").html('Login');
                }
              }
            });
          }
          return false;
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="bar bar-header bar-positive" style="margin-bottom:80px;">
      <a href="index.html" class="button button-clear">Home</a>
      <h1 class="title">Login</h1>
    </div>
    <br/><br/>
    <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="username" />
    <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="password" />
    <button id="login">Login</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

email is not defined before

```
$.trim(email)
```

Change it to and the connecting... will appear

```
$.trim(username)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
change $.trim(email).length
```

To

```
 $.trim(username).length
```